# Unable get options from a Select using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, select, xpath, webdriver

I am having difficulty selecting options from a dropdown list using `Selenium` `Webdriver`.  Below is the `HTML` snippet:

```
<span id="id14">
    <div class="stadium-input-row">
        <span class="inputContainer">
            <select id="id1f" class="departurePoint stadiumSelect" onchange="var wcall=..........">
            <option value="">Please select</option>
            <option value="BHX"> Birmingham - (BHX) </option>
            <option value="GLA"> Glasgow - (GLA) </option>
            <option value="LON"> London - (LON) </option>
            <option value="MAN"> Manchester - (MAN) </option>............
```

The select tag `id` changes each time the DOM is loaded.

The select tag is greyed out until it is interacted with.

My code

```
Select oSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//select)[1]"));
oSelect.selectByVisibleText("Birmingham");
```

Error

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate element
>   with text: Birmingham

In debugging mode, the dropdown does not seem to be activated (clicked) by the driver.

Comment: Use `.selectByVisibleText("Birmingham - (BHX)");` as my provided answer..it works for me...

Comment: sorry this doesn't work as the element is not visible

Comment: But according to your exception it's seems like selenium find the selectbox but could not select the option by provided text..

Comment: I tried your same code, I got same error but when I changed `oSelect.selectByVisibleText("Birmingham");` to `oSelect.selectByVisibleText("Birmingham - (BHX)")` it worked fine...

Comment: Why are you going to click on dropdown... no need here if you want to select option from dropdown... you need to just find the drop down element and pass it to `new Select()`...and work with this...it will self select the option which you provided..

Comment: using the correct text results in an element not visible exception as stated in my comment

Comment: did you tried with index as `oSelect.selectByIndex(1);`???

Comment: or by value `oSelect.selectByValue("BHX");`??

Comment: Did you tried to find select box using `WebDriverWait`????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a weird (at least it's weird to me) thing going on on that site. The `SELECT` that you are trying to access is permanently hidden (which means it can't be interacted with using Selenium). Users interact with `DIV`s, etc. via a fake dropdown (it's not a `SELECT`) and the result of those selections are stored in the hidden `SELECT`. There are two ways to accomplish your task.

1. Deal with what you can see.

   This is really a pain on this site. I think it can be ultimately done but I don't want to spend any more time on it myself so I'll show you the door and you'll have to pick up where I left off. The code below will open the departure dropdown. From there, you find the departure airport and click on it. Done. Harder than it sounds...

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.custom-select.departurePoint.airportSelect")).click();
   ```
2. Cheat and use `JavascriptExecutor`.

   NOTE: By doing this you are no longer executing a real user scenario since users can't click on hidden elements or inject Javascript commands into the page. As long as you are OK with this, here's a sample.

   This code executes Javascript on the page using the `JavascriptExecutor`. You pass the function a string you are looking for in the options, e.g. you can pass "EMA" or "East Midlands - (EMA)" or anywhere inbetween. The JS code will grab the hidden SELECT, search through the OPTIONS, and select the first that matches.

   Also note: You will not see the UI update with the selection. Once you click SEARCH, it will work. I have tried it myself and it works.

   Yet another note: I use Eclipse as my editor so the `// @formatter:off` you see in the code below keeps Eclipse from wrapping/reformatting the extra long string that contains the JS code. You can leave or remove it as you like. I like it there because I can still read the JS code with it formatted and indented like it is and I don't want Eclipse messing it up.

   ```
   selectOption("EMA");

   public void selectOption(String option)
   {
       // @formatter:off
       String script =
           "function selectOption(s) {\r\n" +
           "   var sel = document.querySelector('select.departurePoint.airportSelect');\r\n" +
           "   for (var i = 0; i < sel.options.length; i++)\r\n" +
           "   {\r\n" +
           "       if (sel.options[i].text.indexOf(s) > -1)\r\n" +
           "       {\r\n" +
           "           sel.options[i].selected = true;\r\n" +
           "           break;\r\n" +
           "       }\r\n" +
           "   }\r\n" +
           "}\r\n" +
           "return selectOption('" + option + "');";

       // @formatter:on
       ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script);
   }
   ```

Comment: I have a love/hate relationship with questions like this. I love the puzzle aspect of it but I hate sometimes how long it takes to figure them out. So, you better upvote this 500x, accept it as the answer, and provide me your firstborn for all the work I did on this one... lol.

Comment: I am returning to this problem after a long hiatus.  The solution you gave (Javascript Executor) *was* working but now I can't seem to get it to work.  perhaps I am passing the wrong css selector to the code? I am passing select.selection-component but this is not quite right I think because the page refreshes on clicking 'Search' and does not peform a search. This is on https://www.club18-30.com/club18-30

Answer (score 0):

As your `exception` clearly says `Cannot locate element with text: Birmingham` means it compares with whole visible text option so you should try as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement select = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(.//select)[1]")));
Select oSelect = new Select(select);
oSelect.selectByVisibleText("Birmingham - (BHX)");
```

or

```
oSelect.selectByIndex(1);
```

or

```
oSelect.selectByValue("BHX");
```

**Edited** :- If unfortunately none of the above solution works you should try using `JavascriptExecutor` as below :-

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("var select = arguments[0]; for(var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++){ if(select.options[i].text.indexOf(arguments[1]) != -1){ select.options[i].selected = true; } }",
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//select)[1]")),
            "Birmingham");
```

Hope it will help you..:)

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do:

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='stadium-input-row']//select")).findElements(By.tagName("option"));
```

that will create you list of option tags as WebElement objects

or

```
Select oSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='stadium-input-row']//select"));
```

or just take the select as WebElement object

```
WebElement selectElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='stadium-input-row']//select"));
```

Hovering element

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement hoverElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='stadium-input-row']//select"));
action.moveToElement(hoverElement);
action.click().build().perform();
```

Comment: Using the first method, it does indeed create a list of tags because I can see 41 elements in the List when debugging.  The issue I have is exposing an element to Selenium so it can interact with it.  If, for example, I do:  options.get(1).click,  I still get an org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException with each method suggested.

Comment: try to hover on the select and after that interact with it - i will add the code

Comment: the dropdown is not activated on hover, rather on click

Comment: you hovering on the select element and after that clicking on the option you need, try it.

Comment: unfortunately I'm still getting an element not visible exception

Comment: I have found an example of the kind of dropdown I need toi select from here: https://www.club18-30.com/club18-30

Answer (score -1):

Select will not work in all the situations. Try this code

```
List <WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("Target Element with Options"));
    String element;
    for(int i=0;i<options.size();i++)
    {
        element = options[i].get(i).getAttribute("value");
        if(element.equals("BHX")){
            options.get(i).click();
        }
    }
```